# ValueError: "<User: harry1>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I need help with Django web Framework I cannot solve this problem or I cannot identify the source of the problem. Please help me with this problem the main problem is written in the title.

**Here is my traceback for the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Documents\CodingFox\CodingFox_final\CodingFox\Users\views.py", line 37, in registeration_form
    form.save()
  File "D:\Documents\CodingFox\CodingFox_final\CodingFox\Users\forms.py", line 18, in save   
    user = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 131, in save
    user.save()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 536, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 851, in __init__
    raise ValueError('"%r" needs to have a value for field "%s" before '
ValueError: "<User: harry1>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

**Models.py file**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
import cv2

class Profile(models.Model):
    user =models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    cover_img = models.ImageField(default='default.png',upload_to='cover_pics')
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')
    # bio = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
    def save(self ,*args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save( *args, **kwargs)
        img = cv2.imread(self.image.path)
        output_size = cv2.resize(img,(300,300))
        cv2.imwrite(self.image.path, output_size)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.forms import models 
from .models import Profile

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email=forms.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password1','password2']

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['cover_img','image']

class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','password']
```

**Base.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    {% block head %}

    {% endblock head %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="title" content="CodingFox: Pre Written Code snippets">
    <meta name="description"
        content="CodingFox can enhance the speed of programming by giving them pre-written code snippets.">

    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://CodingFox.com/">
    <meta property="og:title" content="CodingFox: Pre Written Code snippets">
    <meta property="og:description"
        content="CodingFox can enhance the speed of programming by giving them pre-written code snippets.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="resoures/img/For_website.png">

    <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
    <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://CodingFox.com/">
    <meta property="twitter:title" content="CodingFox: Pre Written Code snippets">
    <meta property="twitter:description"
        content="CodingFox can enhance the speed of programming by giving them pre-written code snippets.">
    <meta property="twitter:image" content="resoures/img/For_website.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendors/css/1.3 grid.css.css' %}">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendors/css/normalize.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendors/css/prism-1.css' %}">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png' %}">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="{% static 'favicon/android-icon-192x192.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'favicon/favicon-32x32.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="{% static 'favicon/favicon-96x96.png' %}">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'favicon/favicon-16x16.png' %}">
    <link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'favicon/manifest.json' %}">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="{% static 'favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png' %}">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <script src="{% static 'vendors/js/prism-1.js' %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <img src="{% static 'resoures/img/For_website.png' %}" alt="Logo_img" />
        <div class="ion-md-menu nav_icon" id="nav_clickable"></div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="nav_icon-link"><a href="{% url 'New-post_page' %}" class="link">New Post</a></div>
        <div class="nav_icon-link"><a href="{% url 'login_page' %}" class="link"><span class="ion-md-search"></span></a></div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="nav_icon-link"><a href="{% url 'login_page' %}" class="link">Login</a></div>
        <div class="nav_icon-highlight"><a href="{% url 'register_page' %}" class="link">Register</a></div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="nav_box" id="nav_box">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="" class="nav_box-link--person_img"><img src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="person-img"
                    srcset="" /></a>
        <a href="" class="nav_box-link link"><span class="ion-md-home"></span>&nbsp; {{ user.username }}</a>
        {% else %}
            {% comment %} <a href="#" class="nav_box-link link">Unknown</a> {% endcomment %}
        {% endif %}
            
            
            <a href="#" class="nav_box-link" id="theme_box_toggle"><span class="ion-md-moon"></span>&nbsp; Theme</a>
            <div class="nav_box-theme_box" id="theme_box">
                <p>Change the color scheme to Dark colors.</p>
                <h4>Toggle Theme</h4>
                <input type="checkbox" name="" id="nav_box-theme_box-checkbox" />
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="nav_box-link" id="lang_box_toggle"><span class="ion-md-code"></span>&nbsp; Languages</a>
            <ul class="nav_box_language_box" id="lang_box">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-logo-html5">&nbsp; HTML</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-logo-css3">&nbsp; CSS</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-logo-python">&nbsp; Python</span></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-logo-javascript">&nbsp; JavaScript</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <a href="#" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-md-options"></span>&nbsp; Settings</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-md-save"></span>&nbsp; Saved Posts</a>
                {% comment %} <a href="#" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-md-home"></span>&nbsp; Home</a> {% endcomment %}
                <hr />
                <a href="{% url 'logout_page' %}" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-md-log-out"></span>&nbsp; Log out</a>
            {% else %}   
                <a href="{% url 'login_page' %}" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-md-log-in"></span>&nbsp; Login</a>
                <hr />
                <a href="{% url 'register_page' %}" class="nav_box-link"><span class="ion-md-person-add"></span>&nbsp; Register</a>
            {% endif %}
            
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="message-box">
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>
            {% if message.level == DEFAULT_MESSAGE_LEVELS.ERROR %}Important: {% endif %}
        {{ message }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
    </div>
    {% block category %}

    {% endblock category %}
    {% block Post_loading %}

    {% endblock Post_loading %}
    {% block post %}

    {% endblock post %}

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'resoures/js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'resoures/js/script-jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'vendors/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**signup_form.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    <head>
        {% block head %}
          <title>CodingFox | Register</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'resoures/css/login.css' %}" />
        {% endblock head %}
      </head>
    <body>
        {% block post %}  
          <form action="" method="post" class="signup_form">
          {% csrf_token %}
            <h1>Welcome New User!</h1>
            {% comment %} <label for="signup_email">Email :</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            <label for="signup_username">Username :</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <label for="signup_password">Password :</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password"> {% endcomment %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
            {% comment %} <h4><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></h4> {% endcomment %}
            <input type="submit" value="Register">
            <hr>
            <p>Already have a account?</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Login</a>
          </form>
        {% endblock post %}
          
        
    </body>
```

**Views.py**

```
def registeration_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('login_page')
    else:
        form=UserRegistrationForm()
    context = {
        'title':'Register',
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request,'signup_form.html',context)
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.registeration_form, name='register_page'),
]
```

Can you please give me a solution? This thing just worked a week ago but it's giving errors now. It is also giving errors for creating Post.

Comment: In general you need to first create an object and store it in the DB (which will give you the ID), before you can use it in any M2M relation.

Comment: I understand that but I am getting an error in creating any object like registering a user or creating a new post.

Comment: Please include your form's code.

Comment: I can not see it from the code your posted, but there must be a M2M relation somewhere. Maybe in some part, you did not post? Would suggest to debug line by line to see where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: I have added all the code including HTML codes.